# gwt: How do I write a clone() method that doesn't result in "The method clone() is undefined for the type Object" error?

Tags: gwt, clone

I'm using GWT 2.4.  I have this class, which overrides the clone() method ...

```
public class Attribute implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    ...

public Object clone() {
    Object ret = null;
    try {
        ret = super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
    }   // try
    return ret;
}
```

Sadly, when I try and run my GWT test class, I get the compilation error

```
[ERROR] Line 113: The method clone() is undefined for the type Object
```

Anyone know how I can rewrite the above to avoid the compile errors while preserving the functionality?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.clone` is not supported by the GWT compiler. If you really need support for it you can follow a work around suggested in this GWT issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5068

Comment: This answers the question, but here is a link as an alternative solution to clone() (for the folks who stumbled here looking for a solution since clone() won't work): https://stackoverflow.com/a/49248240/2129418